# How can I make the most of Use the Force?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition, optimization

So I have a Force wizard character I'm making for a Star Wars Saga Edition game, who has specialised in the **Use the Force** skill. There are various ways to use the **Use the Force** skill in place of other skills or rolls. For instance, **Force Perception** talent lets you substitute your UtF skill for perception.

How can I make full use of this skill, and use it as my 'crutch' to help out in replacing skills/combat rolls?

(N.B. I don't mean to say I want to roll the skill as it is, but I want to *substitute* rolls for a UtF roll.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [Talent Summary](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cts=1330815344380&ved=0CG8QFjAHOAo&url=http://swrpgrc.com/files/Saga%2520Edition%2520Resources/SWSE%2520Talent%2520Summary%2520%28Reb%2520Era%29.pdf&ei=SKFST_nvFYKP0QGj2vjyBQ&usg=AFQjCNHZpf_jL2BibSwArEVFkW2clAdJeA&sig2=jRRO5xFTCVGQECjubs9cEw), there are a preposterous number of items that involve "use the force."

Here are the ones I consider most cheesy:

- Adept Negotiator -> Force Persuasion: replaces persuasion, can pacify people by rolling it
- Consular's Vitality some healing at the expense of a penalty to use the force
- Far Seeing-> "watchCircle Initiate" and its tree: replace farseeing with use the force, add force points to allies, UtF versus will to reroll ally missed attack, and boost to reflex
- Force intuition: UtF instead of initiative. Cause that's balanced.
- Clear mind -> : avoid detection via UtF, greater levels provide party invisibility
- Block: Blocks melee using UtF
- Deflect: Deflects ranged using UtF
- Shii-Cho: penalty to blocking/deflecting only -2
- Soresu: get UtF reroll
- Illusion tree: Does what it says on the tin.
- Move Massive Objcet: throw huge things with UtF

Here are the UtF "replace" skill talents:

- Will to resist: UtF -> Will
- Force Perception: UtF -> Perception
- Instinctive Navigation: UtF -> Use Computer (for astrogation)
- Charm Beast: UtF -> Persuasion for animals
- Force Treatment: UtF -> Treat Injury. Medpacks are for sissies.
- Insight of the Force: UtF -> Knowledge
- Force Deception: UtF -> Deception
- Folded Space Mastery: UtF to shove an object through hyperspace without a hyperdrive.
- White Current Adept: UtF -> Stealth

From [here](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?595888-Star-Wars-Saga-Maxing-Out-Your-Use-The-Force-Skills&p=14501452#post14501452):

```
> Fluidity (shapers of kro var talent) - acrobatics 
> Force Deception (sith talent) - deception 
> Force Intuition (jedi talent) - initiative
> Force Perception (sense talent) - perception 
> Force Persuasion (jedi talent, pre-req adept negotiator) - persuasion 
> Force Pilot (sense talent) - pilot 
> Force Treatment (jedi knight or force adept talent) - treat injury 
> Insight of the Force (jedi knight talent) - knowledges
> Instinctive Navigation (sense talent, pre-req force pilot) - use computer for astrogation 
>White Current Adept (white current adept talent) - stealth
```

Short version: There exist more talents than you can take. What kind of specialization are you interested in?

Comment: My Force Wizard is a generalist...so nothing really. I've still yet to find out what we're missing in the team. So this is still an excellent answer.

Comment: Wait, wait... does Folded Space Mastery *really* do *that?* And if wearing a spacesuit, can I push the *suit* through space (with me in it) to go FTL *sans* ship? *And live?*

Comment: @HeyICanChan That's a great question. Maybe it should BE a question?

Comment: @Sandwich Unfortunately, I don't know enough about *Star Wars: SAGA Edition* to even ask that question. I was just surprised that hurling *oneself* **FTL** *using the Force* might be a thing. (And, moreso because, upon reflection, I can't think of any scenes offhand in the 6 films or the *Clone Wars* television series wherein a dude uses an actual, for-reals spacesuit; *Empire* has our heroes in face masks on an asteroid, but that's as far as I can go.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, you can't use Fold Space that way. You can use Fold Space to teleport objects that you can see within line of sight. Folded Space Mastery then allows you to teleport a ship and its contents without a hyperdrive, but only when you are piloting it. It specifically says that. No fold-spacing any random thing anywhere in the universe. But it does allow you to save points for upgrading your ship by removing the hyperspace drive to use on other things. Also makes it easier to recover your ship from thieves because they can't jump away, and have to run through normal space.

Comment: Would I be considered a stickler if I asked for book sourcing?